# Data inserting to ODBC destination with powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, odbc

I need to load data table to ODBC driver connection with powershell.
With OLEDB and SQL server we can use Bulk Copy and insert data quickly.

Is there such posibility with ODBC ?

I'm using powershell because it shoud have the best support for these kind of opperations,
but my current code doesn't utillise an of the dlls.

So my code firstly needs to create an insert statements with **two for loops** and iterate on every row and hold it in its memory,
and then to construct INSERT INTO with 1000 rows, and then repeat same thing.

Am i doomed to something like this ?

```
    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $tabledump= $src_cmd.ExecuteReader()
    $Datatable.Load($tabledump)

    foreach ($item in $Datatable.Rows) {


        $f +=1


        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $item.ItemArray.Length; $i++) {
            $items = $item[$i] -replace "'" , "''"
            $val +="'"+ $items + "',"
        }

        $vals +=  $val




        if ($f % 1000 -eq 0 -or $f -eq $row_cnt) {

            $values = [system.String]::Join(" ", $vals)
            $values = $values.TrimEnd(",")


            $cols =  [system.String]::Join(",", $columns)


            $postgresCommand = "Insert Into $dst_schema.$dst_table ($cols) values $values"

            $dest_cmd_.CommandText = $postgresCommand



            $dest_cmd_.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Bad code i admit, any advice on code compositions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Get-ODBCDSN command to retrieve the values of the ODBC connections and use it with a query

```
  $conn.ConnectionString= "DSN=$dsn;"
  $cmd = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
  $conn.open()
  $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  $conn.close()
```

https://www.andersrodland.com/working-with-odbc-connections-in-powershell/

But the ODBC provider doesnt do bulk copy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-bulk-copy-operations/performing-bulk-copy-operations-odbc?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is not new, but i've been fiddeling around looking for a solution and also found nothing, however this post gave me a couple of insights. 
First: There is no such thing as 'Bad Code'. If it works is not bad, heck even if it didn't worked, but helped with something..

Alright, what i did is not the best solution, but i'm trying to import Active Directory data on PostgreSQL, so...
I noticed that you're trying with pgsql as well, so you can use the **COPY** statement.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html 
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/

In my case i used it with a csv file: 
*Assuming you have installed pgsql ODBC driver

```
$DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)};Server=$ServerInstance;Port=$Port;Database=$Database;Uid=$Username;Pwd=$(ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $Password);"
$DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString
try 
{
    $ADFObject = @()
    $ADComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Some,OU=OrgU,OU=On,DC=Domain,DC=com" -Properties Description,DistinguishedName,Enabled,LastLogonTimestamp,modifyTimestamp,Name,ObjectGUID | Select-Object Description,DistinguishedName,Enabled,LastLogonTimestamp,modifyTimestamp,Name,ObjectGUID
    foreach ($ADComputer in $ADComputers) {
        switch ($ADComputer.Enabled) {
            $true {
                $ADEnabled = 1
            }
            $false {
                $ADEnabled = 0
            }
        }
        $ADFObject += [PSCustomObject] @{
            ADName = $ADComputer.Name
            ADInsert_Time = Get-Date
            ADEnabled = $ADEnabled
            ADDistinguishedName = $ADComputer.DistinguishedName
            ADObjectGUID = $ADComputer.ObjectGUID
            ADLastLogonTimestamp = [datetime]::FromFileTime($ADComputer.LastLogonTimestamp)
            ADModifyTimestamp = $ADComputer.modifyTimestamp
            ADDescription = $ADComputer.Description
        }
    }
    $ADFObject | Export-Csv $Env:TEMP\TempPsAd.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
    docker cp $Env:TEMP\TempPsAd.csv postgres_docker:/media/TempPsAd.csv
    $DBConn.Open()
    $DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand()
    $DBCmd.CommandText = @"
        COPY AD_Devices (ADName,ADInsert_Time,ADEnabled,ADDistinguishedName,ADObjectGUID,ADLastLogonTimestamp,ADModifyTimestamp,ADDescription)
        FROM '/media/TempPsAd.csv'
        DELIMITER ','
        CSV HEADER
"@
    $DBCmd.ExecuteReader()
    $DBConn.Close()
    docker exec postgres_docker rm -rf /media/TempPsAd.csv
    Remove-Item $Env:TEMP\TempPsAd.csv -Force
} 
catch 
{ 
    Write-Error "$($_.Exception.Message)"
    continue 
}
```

Hope it helps! 
Cheers!